# How to get values from Deserialized JSON object?

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to import JSON, parse it and be able to use it throughout my app. For example I would like to loop through and be able to print out the years. How would I go about doing that?

**Code**:

```
var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

try 
{
    List<RootObject> list = (List<RootObject>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(result);

}

catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine (e);
}
```

**JSON**:

```
{
    "ROWCOUNT": 3,
    "COLUMNS": [
        "YEARMFG",
        "MAKE",
        "MODEL",
        "ENGINE",
        "TOWLIMIT",
        "NOTE1",
        "NOTE2"
    ],
    "DATA": {
        "YEARMFG": [
            2012,
            2012,
            2012
        ],
        "MAKE": [
            "Chevrolet/GMC",
            "Chevrolet/GMC",
            "Chevrolet/GMC"
        ],
        "MODEL": [
            "Avalanche 1500 4WD",
            "Avalanche 1500 4WD",
            "Avalanche 1500 4WD"
        ],
        "ENGINE": [
            "5.3L V-8",
            "5.3L V-8",
            "5.3L V-8"
        ],
        "TOWLIMIT": [
            5000,
            5500,
            8000
        ],
        "NOTE1": [
            "3.08 axle ratio",
            "3.42 axle ratio",
            "3.42 axle ratio"
        ],
        "NOTE2": [
            "",
            "",
            "Cooling or other accessory package required "
        ]
    }
}
```

**Classes:**

```
public class DATA
{
    public List<int> YEARMFG { get; set; }
    public List<string> MAKE { get; set; }
    public List<string> MODEL { get; set; }
    public List<string> ENGINE { get; set; }
    public List<int> TOWLIMIT { get; set; }
    public List<string> NOTE1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> NOTE2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int ROWCOUNT { get; set; }
    public List<string> COLUMNS { get; set; }
    public DATA DATA { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you currently having? Is there an exception?

Comment: What happens when you run the code you've given us? You appear to be on the right track, so its hard to tell what is currently tripping you up.

Comment: based on what he has shown it appears that he's trying to parse it and it doesn't look correct from first glance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Comment: I was told to add some classes from the JSON using json2csharp. My thought was I would be able to do list.YEARMFG or something like that. How do I access my values from json in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your objects and `GetJson()` just returns the JSON string:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(GetJSON());
foreach (var year in obj.DATA.YEARMFG)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}", year);
}
```

Which should output (based on your sample data):

```
Year: 2012
Year: 2012
Year: 2012
```

Side note: You don't have to deserialize to a `List<RootObject>`. `RootObject` should be a single entity (as it wraps your entire JSON data). So simply deserialize it to a single instance, then access the `DATA` property and iterate over `YEARMFG`.

Comment: Thanks Brad. This worked for me. I'm not sure if this is the semantic way of doing this, but it did work. Seems like I could just get away with having a DATA class instead of both DATA and RootObject.

Comment: You need `root` to decipher the `DATA` property within. You could just use `class RootObject { public DATA DATA { get; set; } }` if that's all you care about though.

Answer (score 0):

You are deserializing a `List<RootObject>`, so each element in the `List` is a `RootObject`.  You can see in your class that `RootObject` has a `DATA` property, which contains a `List<string>` of the `YEARMFG`.

You should be able to access the items in your `list` like so:

`list.DATA.YEARMFG` will give you a list of the years for a given item.

If you would like to display them individually, you can loop through the list:

```
foreach (var yr in list.DATA.YEARMFG)
{
    // handle individual year info here
}
```

Comment: I thought that as well. But it only appears I can use `list` to Add, Count, Add Range, etc...normal Collections.List properties.